# conditions equivalent to singularity of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

What conditions are equivalent to **singularity** of matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$.
**a.** $\dim(ker A) \ge 0$
**b.** There is exist vector $b$ such that $Ax=b$ is contradictory.
**c.** $rank(A^T) < n$

**a.** is true for each matrix, in other words $\dim$ can't be negative.
**c.** $rank(A^T) = rank(A)$.  Singularity means that some vector (row) is linearly **dependent** on other vectors.  Then, we may using elementary operations on rows, reset this row -> so it is true that $rank(A) < n$

Is it correct ?
When it comes to **b.** I suppose that it is true, however I can't prove it.

Comment: First one needs a strict inequality.

Comment: $\dim \ker I = 1 \ge 0$ but $I$ is not singular.

Comment: Is it not true that: *if matrix $A$ is singular then $\dim(ker A) \ge 0$* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b. is equivalent to the fact that dimension of the kernel of the matrix is not null. By saying that there exists a vector b so that Ax=b is contradictory, it wants to say that there exists some vector b that belongs to the kernel of the matrix a.

As that b would belong to the kernel of the matrix a, we could not generate it through the product Ax. For example, supose the next matrix $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 3 \\
0 & 0  \\ \end{array} \right)$, whose range is obviusly spanned by $x^T=(1,0)$, and whose kernel is spanned by $x_k^T=(0,1)$. The n if we write the product $Ax=b$ in terms of the components of b, and take $b=x_k^T$, we see that:

$0=x_1+3x_2$

$k=0+0$

I am taking k instead of 1 to show that all the vectors from the kernel of A would not satisfy the equation. As you can see the second component of x leds to a contradiction as $k\neq 0,if k\neq0$, and k is not zero as we are assuming that vector b should be in the kernel of A.

Obviously yif the dimension of the kernel is null, there won't exist such a vector b.

Comment: I don't understand why it is not possible that $Ax=w$ where $w$ is non-zero and $w\in \ker A$

Comment: Because you can write the product $Ax=\sum_j A_{ij}b_j$, meaning that B has to be a linear combinación of the columns of A. That implies that b has to lie on the range of A, so if b cannot belong to the kernel of A.

Comment: Can you tell me what about **a.**?

Comment: $Ax$ is linear combination of columns $A$. However, I don't understand why $b\in \ker A$ and $b\neq 0$ can't be combination of columns $A$ ?

Answer (score 0):

a. Condition should be $dim \ker{A}>0$, as that implies that there is some column that is a linear combinación of the others. That would imply that the dimension of the range of A < n, implying that the rank of A is < n. Finally, that implies that the determinant of A is 0, so the Matrix is singular.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to add as comment, but I confused.

Comment: And $dim \ker{A}$ cannot be equal to zero as that would imply that the Matrix is full rank (as dim(range(A))=n, from the rank nullity theorem), implying a determinant different to zero, and so non-singularity.